# Django Views:Getting ListView inside Detailed View

Tags: django, django-views

I have the following setup. I have Teachers, which can have many Students. Both of them are Django Users. Students can leave reviews for Teachers. I'm building the Teacher Detail View. That is the url `/teachers/1` where `/teachers/` is the List View.

Now the problem:

I want all reviews, left by the user to be visible in the given teacher view. That would correspond to a 'ListView' within a DetailedView.
**Urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.TeacherView.as_view(), name='detail'),
]
```

**Models.py**

```
class Teacher(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='Teacher')
    availability = models.BooleanField(default=False)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

class Student(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='Student')
    teacher = models.OneToOneField(Teacher, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='Student')
    reviewed = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

class Review(models.Model):
    teacher = models.OneToOneField(Teacher, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='Teacher')
    student = models.OneToOneField(Student, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='Student')
    star = models.IntegerField(default=5)
    body = models.TextField()
```

*And finally the main problem* - **views.py**

```
class IndexView(ListView):
    # context_object_name = 'latest_teacher_list'

    def get_queryset(self):
        """Return the last five published questions."""
        return Teacher.objects.all()[:5]


class TeacherView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Teacher

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        # Call the base implementation first to get a context
        context = super(TeacherView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        # Add extra context from another model
        context['reviews'] = Review.objects.filter(teacher_pk=pk)
        return context
```

This doesn't work, it complains that pk is not defined. What it does in my head, is get the **pk** from URL, then finds all review objects where user.teacher.pk (or teacher.pk or teacher_pk) = pk.

I tried playing around with **kwags and replacing by pk, without success.

Also, as additional question I would like to display the average rating.

I'm thinking of `rating = Review.objects.filter(teacher_pk=pk).aggregate(Avg('star')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the pk from `self.kwargs`:

```
context['reviews'] = Review.objects.filter(teacher_pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
```